# CXF client not use Proxy server in a SSL request to retrieve the WSDL

Tags: java, ssl, wsdl, cxf, http-proxy

We have a CXF (2.7.X) client (see code below) in a Java 1.6.0_45 application.
The CXF client calls a Soap WS through a proxy server.
Despite all our efforts, that CXF client performs some requests directly to the WS bypassing the proxy.

The only solution for the moment is to force proxy on the JVM options.
But this solution is not acceptable.

Is there a pb in our code ?
I have not found any clue on the internet or on the CXF jira .

```
// work only if i define proxy on jvm
/*
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost","87.65.43.21");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "808");
System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "87.65.43.21");
System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "808");
*/

// initialize ws
URL wsdlLocation = new URL("https://12.34.56.78:8443/mockHelloWorldSoapBinding?WSDL");
QName qName = new QName("http://my.webservice.com", "HelloWorldService");
HelloWorldService helloWorldService = new HelloWorldService(wsdlLocation, qName);
HelloWorld port = helloWorldService.getHelloWorld();
HTTPConduit httpConduit = (HTTPConduit) ClientProxy.getClient(port).getConduit();

// add proxy parameters
HTTPClientPolicy policy = new HTTPClientPolicy();
policy.setProxyServer("87.65.43.21");
policy.setProxyServerPort(808);
policy.setAllowChunking(false);
httpConduit.setClient(policy);

// call ws
String response = port.sayHello("world");
```

Comment: I realised that the direct call (the call that doesn't use the proxy server) is the one that retrieves the WSDL.
Is anybody had already saw that ?